# Memory management for an instance at higher depth

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say i have an following class in javascript

```
class A {
  constructor(createB){
    if(createB === undefined) this.b = new B();
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(){
    super(false);
  }
}

var global = {};
global.a = new A();

delete global.a;
```

now what will happen to the instance of `B`?
will that instance of `B` and its memory automatically destroyed?

Comment: Why does `B` inherit from `A`? Does that have something to do with your question?

Comment: JS is a garbage-collected language. You don't have to do "memory management".

Comment: yes, actually i just want to clear out some doubts when its comes into existence of inheritance.

Comment: Inheritance doesn't change anything about reachability. You still got two distinct objects, regardless what classes they are instances of.

Comment: Is that means, deleting a will auto remove b?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what the `delete` operator does. It removes properties from objects, nothing else. In your case, the `.a` property was the last reference to the `new A` instance, making it eligible for GC as well; but `global.a = null` would've had the same effect.